# how can I set up a location in my mkannotationview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In my code I'm adding a single pin to the map. So far I'm doing it like that:

```
let pinLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
   latitude: locationTemp.latitude,
   longitude: locationTemp.longitude
)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = pinLocation

self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

But now, since I want to create a custom pin image, I've read I have to switch to `MKAnnotationView`. But I don't know how to set the location of this annotation so that it shows the same annotation as my previous pin.

I tried this:

```
var pinView = MKAnnotationView()
pinView.image = UIImage(named:"MyCustomPin")
```

but I cannot find a way of setting here my `locationTemp` data.

Answer (score -2):

If you check out the documentation and you'll see MKAnnotationView has an init method

```
init(annotation annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

So there's the link between the view and the co-ordinates.

Comment: ok thanks, but I still am not sure how could I just use my plain gps data (stored in `locationTemp`) and use it in my case... can you show me some short example?

Comment: It depends exactly how you want to do things. Using a custom annotation can get pretty complex and involved (you can change color, shape, image, make it pulse, make it animate, have popouts with static or dynamic content etc.). If you just want to start with something simple maybe looking for a tutorial on MKPinAnnotationView, instead of MKAnnotationView, will suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm, all I want is to display a plain `MKAnnotationView` on map with specific coordinates. I would use `MKPinAnnotationView` but then I won't be able to set up a custom image instead of apple's default pin

Comment: I had a look if my use of MKAnnotationView would be suitable for posting as an example, but its far too long and complex to post as an answer and would probably confuse more than clarify as it moves around as live co-ordincates are fed into it in a continuous stream rather than it being linked at init time to an MKAnnotation, which is what you want. Sorry. You should be able to google for tutorials on MKAnnotationView, that's how I got started, I was able to find lots of examples.